# Is Rover opening sound in crazyhouse opening theory?

Tags: opening, crazyhouse

The rover opening 1. a4 is played a lot on the lichess server and there have been some high level games in it. The opening is not gaining any initiative or tempo, it is just rook lifting prematurely, which is a terrible idea in normal chess, but works a bit in crazyhouse.

Does anyone have a lichess study or a good explanation on how to get good lines out of the Rover opening.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to rook lift this early in crazy house. Lichess's carzy house computer actually says that 1.e4 gives white a +2.3 advantage and 1.a4 gives white -1.0. In crazy house, you have to get your pieces out as fast as possible.